# More than one wiki and security access in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

In my azure devops portal, I want to have multiple wikis each containing information specific to different groups and teams. How can I create more than one wiki? When I try to clone, it looks like it tries to clone a wiki repository, which I think is more about making changes to an existing wiki repo.

Alternatively, if I can restrict access to some of the pages in the wiki, that is fine too.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not able to create more than one wiki per team project at present.

There has been a related user voice, you could vote up and monitor the progress:

> **Allow creation of multiple Wikis per Team Project**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/379600/allow-creation-of-multiple-wikis-per-team-project.html

```
Alternatively, if I can restrict access to some of the pages in the wiki, that is fine too.
```

Unfortunately, we do not have independent permission setting based on page level. We could only mange whole wiki permission from [Manage Wiki permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops).

You could give a try with  Adithya Ramasubramanian [MSFT]'s suggestion in above user voice:

We have the ability to publish code as wiki where a repository can be published into a Wiki. All the markdown files in that repo goes as a Wiki. With this, you can also manage permissions for the Repo which will be inherited into the Wiki.

Try to use branch security to separate different users or groups.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the drop down menu in the `Wikis` bread crumb to create additional wikis using `Publish code as wiki`

[image]